# dockerized react - how to auto enable hot reloading

Tags: reactjs, docker, hot-reload

I'm dockerizing MERN apps at the moment.

The apps is divided into 2, react app at frontend and express app at backend.

The goals is to enable hot reloading at the react app.

Here's my `docker-compose.yml` file :

```
version: '3'

services:
  mango:
    container_name: mango
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 3000:80
    volumes:
      - ./docker/app/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./build:/usr/share/nginx/html
    depends_on:
      - mango-builder
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    networks:
      - local_network

  mango-builder:
    container_name: mango-builder
    image: node:12.13.0
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: bash -c "rm -rf /app/package-lock.json && rm -rf /app/yarn.lock && yarn && if [ `$NODE_ENV` = `development` ]; then yarn run start; else yarn run build; fi"
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"
    networks:
      - local_network

networks:
  local_network:
```

Note that:

1. When the `NODE_ENV` is set to `development`, it will run the `yarn run start` command.
2. yarn will try to recompile dependencies whenever there's a react component change
3. `mango-builder` will be built first before the `mango`
4. The `build` folder was generated by `mango-builder`, then it's attached into `mango` (check the `volumes` section)
5. The react app is running well at browser

When I try to change the react modules, somehow the hot reloading is not working.

I have a feeling I need to make the `yarn run start` keep running in the background, but I don't know how to do it.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you need to use Docker at this point in development?  Doubly true since the application runs in the browser and can't take advantage of any Docker networking features.  Run `yarn start` in your host Node environment for day-to-day development.

Comment: the dev requesting it, he wants to implement it in his local environment too, otherwise I would have kept it simple :)